# Configuring MVC 5 project with service layer and DI and UOW

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

In the past I have always called the repositories directly from the controller, but that is a bad practice and now I am implementing a "Business Layer" to my project.

Would I have two UnitOfWorks?  One for the Service and then one for the repositories?

BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IUnitOfWorkService UnitOfWorkService;
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    protected BaseController(IUnitOfWorkService unitOfWorkService)
    {
        UnitOfWorkService = unitOfWorkService;
        _employeeService = unitOfWorkService.EmployeeService;
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public HomeController(IUnitOfWorkService unitOfWorkService) : base(unitOfWorkService)
    {
        _employeeService = unitOfWorkService.EmployeeService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var emp = _employeeService.GetEmployee(employeeId);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

EmployeeService:

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepo;

    public EmployeeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _employeeRepo = unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository;
    }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        return _employeeRepo.GetEmployee(employeeId);
    }

    ...
}
```

EmployeeRepository

```
public class EfEmployeeRepository : EfRepository, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EfEmployeeRepository(SqlContext context) : base(context) { }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        var employee = Context.Employees
                    .SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);


        return employee != null ? employee.ToDomain() : null;
    }
}
```

### Unit of Work

IUnitOfWorkService:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkService : IDisposable
{
    IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; }
}
```

UnitOfWorkService:

```
public class UnitOfWorkService : IUnitOfWorkService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    private EmployeeService _employeeService;

    public UnitOfWorkService()
    {
        _unitOfWork = new EfUnitOfWork();
    }


    public IEmployeeService EmployeeService
    {
        get { return _employeeService ?? (_employeeService = new EmployeeService(_unitOfWork)); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository { get; }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class EfUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SqlContext _context;

    private EfEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository
    {
        get { return _employeeRepository ?? (_employeeRepository = new EfEmployeeRepository(_context)); }
    }

    public EfUnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new SqlContext();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### Register Dependencies

```
builder.RegisterType<EfUnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWorkService>().As<IUnitOfWorkService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: do you need 2 UoW's?

Comment: Other examples I look at use the generic repository pattern and it looks like they only have 1 UoW.  I haven't seen anyone else implement a UoW for the Service and another one for the repository.  The alternative would be to have the controllers accept each service as a parameter and the UoW would be in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class BaseController : Controller
> {
>     protected IUnitOfWorkService UnitOfWorkService;
>     private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
>
>     protected BaseController(IUnitOfWorkService unitOfWorkService)
>     {
>         UnitOfWorkService = unitOfWorkService;
>         _employeeService = unitOfWorkService.EmployeeService;
>     }
> }
> public class HomeController : BaseController
> {
>     private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
>
>     public HomeController(IUnitOfWorkService unitOfWorkService) : base(unitOfWorkService)
>     {
>         _employeeService = unitOfWorkService.EmployeeService;
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         var emp = _employeeService.GetEmployee(employeeId);
>         ...
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

- I don't see a reason here to have `private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;` in the `HomeController`. It would be better to make the `_employeeService` variable of the `BaseController` `protected` so it can be used by the objects which inherits the `BaseController`.
- Why is the `protected IUnitOfWorkService UnitOfWorkService;` **not** readonly ?

---

**Style**

- Using abbreviations or naming variables is bad practice. Does it hurt to name the variable `IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepo` like `IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository` ?
- It does not hurt to use braces `{}` for single `if` statements but will make the code less error prone. I would like to encourage you to always use them.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with making _employeeRepository part of the base.  Seems to be tying up a base to this field making all inherited classes have it even if they don't want it.  If this was needed I would consider having a BaseEmployeeController but that starts down a slippery deep inheritance tree setup.

Comment: @dreza I didn't say `_employeeRepository` but `_employeeService` which already is part of the `BaseController`.

Comment: @Heslacher Having the `_employeeService` as part of the `BaseController` is a good idea, since every controller will need that anyways.  I forgot to mark the `protected IUnitOfWorkService` as `readonly`.  I'll get that updated.  I agree with you that abbreviations are bad practice and I usually avoid them, but I didn't see any problems with "repo."  I don't think anyone would have problems trying to figure out what that stands for.